Samba preexec / postexex not working smb.conf in Rocky Linux 9
I'm trying to get a simple preexec script run everytime a share is accessed in samba running in Rocky Linux 9.
This is my "testparm" config:
# testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        client signing = required
        disable spoolss = Yes
        load printers = No
        printcap name = /dev/null
        security = USER
        server signing = required
        workgroup = SAMBA
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        cups options = raw
        printing = bsd


[content]
        create mask = 0755
        path = /opt/samba/shared
        read only = No
        root postexec = echo \"%u disconnected from %S from %m (%I)\" >> /tmp/log
        root preexec = echo \"%u connected to %S from %m (%I)\" >> /tmp/log
        valid users = bart
        write list = bart @wheel

Nothing is getting written to /tmp/log
I don't see any messages on samba logs neither.
Any help is appreciated!
Kermes
